# Frontend no longer accessible after dependency updates

Tags: vue.js, flask, uwsgi, dokku

We have a rather standard web app, that consists of a Flask backend and a Vue.js frontend. In production, we use uWSGI to serve that application. We have uWSGI configured to serve frontend pages and access backend calls for their respective routes.

```
[uwsgi]
module = app
callable = create_app()
buffer-size=65535
limit-post=0
wsgi-disable-file-wrapper=true
check-static=./public

# enable threads for sentry
enable-threads = true

# dont show errors if the client disconnected
ignore-sigpipe=true
ignore-write-errors=true
disable-write-exception=true

; redirect all frontend requests that are not static files to the index
route-host = ^$(FRONTEND_HOST_NAME)$ goto:frontend
; also handle if the host name is frontend, for the dokku checks
route-host = ^frontend$ goto:frontend

; continue if its a backend call
route-host = ^$(BACKEND_HOST_NAME)$ last:
route-host = ^backend$ last:

; log and abort if none match
route-run = log:Host Name "${HTTP_HOST}" is neither "$(FRONTEND_HOST_NAME)" nor "$(BACKEND_HOST_NAME)"
route-run = break:500

route-label = frontend
route-if = isfile:/app/src/backend/public${PATH_INFO} static:/app/src/backend/public${PATH_INFO}
route-run = static:/app/src/backend/public/index.html
```

This worked perfectly fine and behaved just like our dev setup, where we use containers for both front- and backend. But after the update of some vulnerable dependencies, trying to access the frontend results in a 404.

In the frontend we moved from vue-cli `~4.5.9` to `~5.0.4`. We long suspected that this might be the main issue, but we're not so sure about that anymore.

We also upgraded from Flask `~1.1` to `^2.0.3` but we kept the version `2.0` of uWSGI. The configuration of that should therefore probably not have changed.

We're treading in the dark on this one. Does anyone of you have any idea on what might be going wrong in here?

I tried to isolate the problem by creating a rather small [setup](https://github.com/goodnic/basic), but have not been able to track down the underlying issue until now.

Comment: Why not just revert to the last working commit, then update dependencies one at a time until you see which one caused the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what it exactly was, but I did in the end upgrade each dependency one by one until all of them were upgraded and things still worked. It must have been something related to the Dockerfile that we use. That one is now slightly more like the old one rather than the one I used previously to doing things one by one.